# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLInputElement] has no method 'prop'

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

when i am trying set radio button checked through jquery.. it gives  me an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLInputElement] has no method
>   'prop'

```
var sub="twoWheeler";
if (vehicleType == sub) {
       alert("asdasd");
       window.opener.document.getElementById("radios1").prop("checked");
}else{

};
```

Comment: post code , we can't analize it like this

Comment: Why close it after OP posted code? Nominating for reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a DOM element reference (in your case an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement)), that is, it doesn't have a [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method which belongs to [jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

Besides that, your code would have no side effect as calling `.prop()` with a single parameter is merely a getter and you're not assigning it to anything. To set the element's `checked` property you can use:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("radios1").checked = true;
```

The above is with Pure JS, the question is tagged with jQuery but using it at this point would only make it harder as you're working through 2 different window objects.

---

Assuming jQuery is included in the same page as `#radios1` you could use:

```
window.opener.$('#radios1').prop('checked', true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTAYn/3/) (may need popups enabled)

Or if jQuery is included only in the page from where you're running the code above, you can use a [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
$('#radios1', window.opener.document).prop('checked', true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTAYn/4/) (may need popups enabled)

But jQuery just makes things more confusing in this case IMO. If you have jQuery in both pages, both would work. The pure JS one is not only faster but also seems cleaner to me.

Comment: @roXon I believe the 15 minutes timer hasn't expired yet. I have more to add to the answer meanwhile. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté (+1 btw) just don't make it too long ;)

Comment: @roXon Yeah just adding some link references for the OP and an alternative to show illustrate the difference between the 2 methods.