# jquery ui uncaught typeerror: object has no method 'prop'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

There are a few similar issues, but none that really seemed to help unfortunately.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><head>
...
<!-- jquery-ui -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/mayofest13/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/development-bundle/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="/sites/mayofest13/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/mayofest13/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

...
```

When the user loads the page, they get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop' jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js:6
```

The worst part is, I don't get this error (Chrome on OS X, Firefox on Ubuntu 12.10, Chrome on Ubuntu 12.10), but two of the site users (both in Chrome on Windows I think) do get this problem.

Originally I thought it was because I was mixing jquery versions (I was using jquery 1.10 or something), so I fixed and now use 1.9.1 - the one this jquery-ui was meant to use I think.  Except the users still seem to have the same problem (though it's possible it's a caching issue for them.)

This happens upon page load, not a result of any action that's being performed.

Has anyone seen this?  I'm going to go home and try my windows laptop and see if those browsers can trigger this.)  I'd post the full site address here, but to get to this page one needs to login, etc.. I can probably set up a page that doesn't require a login, but because I can't seem to trigger the error, I won't know if it has the error.

Thanks,

Comment: Only thing I could think of is that you're not using `.prop()` within a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: that's a very odd error to get using 1.9, and hard to debug without actually seeing the error and tracing it back to it's source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990014/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-htmlinputelement-has-no-method-prop

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - That wouldn't cause that error. At least not if we're talking about the standard jQuery `.prop()` function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the replies.  I'm not using .prop() anywhere..  The main issue is I can't seem to replicate this.  I was hoping someone might have seen this before, thanks everyone.  Tomorrow I'll try to solve this over FB message with the two people who trigger it.

And might use unminimized code to try and find the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mixing the wrong versions of jquery and jquery-ui.  Once I used the right versions, this problem went away.

Comment: Still not sure why only some people got the errors and most didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and found this question looking for the answer.  It my specific situation the problem happens in version 24.0.1312.56 of Chrome in Debian.

```
$("#service_contract").prop("checked", "checked" );
```

It complains there is no prop on the selected object.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop'
```

This error is thrown whether the script is at the end of the document or in the jquery document ready function.
The version of jquery I am using is 1.5.2 hosted by Google.

I tried a newer version of chrome, firefox and iexplore in windows and in linux and the code executes without problem.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery) the prop function isn't available until jquery version 1.6+.  Thus apparently if the version of jquery is out of date, then depending on the version of the browser it may or may not work.